# Android studio code formatting not following the settings

Tags: android, android-studio, code-formatting

I want to copy my project to another directory on my windows 10 PC but whenever I copy the project and open it from the other directory the code formatting settings do not apply to the code formatting. Whenever I format my code with the code formatting shortcut(ctrl + alt + L) the tabbing is turned to 1 space and the code becomes very hard to read. Changing the settings or resetting them to default does not change anything. I also tried to replace the files for code styles but that also does not work. What would you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 1):

AndroidStudio should be the same as IntelliJ IDEA. There you can override formatter settings in **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style**. There you can set Tab size and Indent (I personally suggest 4 spaces).

Comment: Nice, also there are plugins available https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8527-google-java-format

Comment: The problem is that in the settings the indent is 4 spaces but when i format the code it is only 1 space... Changing this number or resetting the settings to default does not change anything.

Comment: Initially you could copy & paste into another editor like VS and format it there, using ctrl+alt+enter then bringing it back to use new setting for tab which should be 4 spaces..